# How to send list of objects from windows store app to web api?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-store-apps, asp.net-web-api

I have a code as shown below

```
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]{new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username",userName),
                                                                  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)});

            // Send Http content to service and authenticate.
            HttpResponseMessage response = await ServiceAPI.CallWebAPI(APIAddress.AUTHENTICATE_USER, content, !isPost);
```

Here I am passing the single parameter of the object User(username and password) in content. What should I do if I need to pass List of Objects (like List) instead of single parameter to web api in .net MVC project. also how should I fetch the value in web api?

Any help will be highly appreciated.